# Checking double quotes in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am getting following exception:-

> EL Expression Unbalanced: ... #{I18N['key_hint_message'] !='""' }

I want to check if my proprty file contains "" for above label

My xhtml code:

```
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{I18N['key_hint_message'] !='&quot;&quot;' }"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use empty operator:

> Empty: *The empty operator is a prefix operation that can be used to determine whether a value is **null or empty***.

This must work:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty I18N['key_hint_message']}"
```

To see how it works exactly check http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaik

Comment: I tried but it then displays $$key_hint_message$$ i.e it displays key

Comment: then `I18N['key_hint_message']` is not valid... it is a real value??

Comment: my proprty entry is  : key_hint_message="" when i make it key_hint_message= i.e blank my page displays $$key_hint_message$$

Comment: Is there a way to check if my label contains "" because thats what is stored  in my property file. Thanks in advance

Comment: thats what exactly does empty operator check if value is null or empty...  problem is not in EL the expression it's the `I18N['key_hint_message']`